# any way to use IN and COUNT in rewriting this query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

```
select count(patientNUM) as totalpatients
from [dbo] (nolock)
where patientId in (
'97210219',
'97210221',
'97210222'
)

50
100
20
```

So each patientsID contain numbers of patients, 100, 20 or 50. And I want to go through each patient rows and to lost them as partial or full. For example if there are 40 of 50 patientID rows, it will list as partial. If 50, it will list as full. Is there way to use count or in at the same time?

So basically I want to create two columns, patientID, and fullorpartial in the second column.

Is there way to go through each row and count each rows and then return and compare the result in a second column?

Comment: `Select patientId ,count(patientNUM) from table group by patientId `?

Comment: @venky__ yeah so basically many patientnum share a same patientID. Lets say for this PatientID 12345, there are total 100 patientnum. If do select patientnum, and get a bunch of rows. If there are 75 of 100 that belongs to 12345 showing, then it is partial, if its 100 out 100, its full. I just want go through each row and county and do a compare with total numbers belong to patientID, then using case scenario in a new column.

Comment: Can you paste some sample data having difficulties in understanding the data .

Comment: How many times does this need to be posted. STOP splattering [nolock hints in your code](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere). And if you must and understand the consequences, at least use the current (and not deprecated) syntax. Don't create more work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to know the "capacity" as well as the `patientId`.  I would suggest a derived table:

```
select t.patientId,
       (case when count(*) < v.capacity then 'partial'
             when count(*) = v.capacity then 'full'
        end) as full_or_partial
from t join
     (values ('97210219', 50),
             ('97210221', 100),
             ('97210222', 20)
     ) v(patientId, capacity)
     on v.patientId = t.patientId
group by t.patientId;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't know what exactly your data looks like and what you want. But try this:

use `over` is a good choice

```
select patientId,count(patientNUM) over(partition by patientId) as totalpatients
from [dbo] (nolock)
where patientId in (
'97210219',
'97210221',
'97210222'
)
```

this will count patientNUM exist times for each patientId.

And about the 'partialorfull' col I think can achieve by using `case`

```
case
when patientId = '97210219' and totalpatients < 50 then 'partial'
when ......   --condition keep going on
else 'full'
end as partialorfull
```